# Java Heap dump and Thread dump in PCF

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there a way to collect the `thread-dump` and `heap-dump` in PCF for Java Apps.

I know that we can `ssh` in to apps and run any linux commands. But the `ssh` is disabled by the operations team. So i wanted to understand if there are any other supported ways in PCF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the Spring Boot Actuator endpoint mentioned by Tim, when `ssh` privleges are not an issue, there's also the [`cf java`](https://github.com/SAP/cf-cli-java-plugin) cli plugin which creates and downloads heap dumps and thread dumps as simple as

`cf java heap-dump APP_NAME > heapdump.hprof`

On top of that there's the [Java Memory Assistant](https://github.com/SAP/java-memory-assistant), which is well integrated into the [Java Buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-java_memory_assistant.md#configuration).

Note that the creation of heap dumps is always restricted to the available disk size to your container. Depending on the size of your heap after a garbage collection (which is triggered automatically when creating a heap dump) it might be necessary to increase disk size of your container via `cf scale APP_NAME -k 2G`.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Pivotal Apps Manager supports interactions with Spring Boot Actuator Endpoints (like thread dump and heap dump) quite nicely https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-4/console/using-actuators.html

Comment: Is there a way to get the heapdump stored in the /vcap/... path when the app crashes and exits? eg. store it in S3 after it crashes but before the app container exits.